How this binomial upper bound can be proven?
Could anyone shed some light in how this inequality can be proven ? (inductive approach is suggested, but if there is another method it would be great too)
$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}\leq\frac{n^n}{k^k(n-k)^{n-k}}$$

Got any bounds?  When $k \in {0,n}$, the rational expression is undefined.

@EricTowers When dealing with combinatorial functions, it is usual to  define $0^0=1.$

It seems like if you write it as $$k^k(n-k)^{n-k}\binom nk\leq n^n$$ you might be able to prove it by finding a counting argument.

Another alternative formulation is: If $\phi(m)=\frac{m!}{m^m}$ then $$\phi(k)\phi(n-k)\geq \phi(n).$$ $\phi(m)$ can be seen as a probability - if given a set of $m$ objects, and you select randomly from the set  $m$ times, with replacement, then $\phi(m)$ is the probability of getting $m$ distinct values.

Hint: using the binomial formula

 $$n^n = (n-k+k)^n =\sum_{i = 0}^n k^i(n-k)^{n-i}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\i\end{matrix}\right)$$

$n^n$ is clearly not less than its indiviual summands. Let $i = k$, then

 $$n^n \geq k^k(n-k)^{n-k}\left(\begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}\right)$$

which is equivalent to the given formula
